# Replacing one character with two in C

Tags: c, replace, character, strchr

I want to replace a character by two characters in my string.

```
void strqclean(const char *buffer)
{
  char *p = strchr(buffer,'?');
  if (p != NULL)
    *p = '\n';
}

int main(){
    char **quest;
    quest = malloc(10 * (sizeof(char*)));
    quest[0] = strdup("Hello ?");
    strqclean(quest[0]);
    printf(quest[0]);
    return;
}
```

This works fine, but in fact I want to replace my "?" by "?\n". strcat doesn't works with pointers is that right ? I can find a solution adding a character in my string and replace it by '\n', but that's not what I really want.

Thanks !

Comment: you can't 1) modify a `const` string and 2) add more data than the string could contain.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried. The posted code won't compile (even when put in a wrapper). `*p = strchr(buffer,'?')` ==> `char *p = strchr(buffer,'?')`

Comment: Your code shouldn't work, `buffer` points to `const` string, you can change the pointer but not what's behind it.

Comment: @Pablo not necessarily since it's a parameter. But it's still _wrong_

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, thank you, I realized that after I pressed ENTER.

Comment: Note that `'\n'` is typically **one** character in a string, but **two** characters in the source code.

Comment: Don't do this: `printf(quest[0]);`, use `puts(quest[0])` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

In your initial answer you mentioned that you wanted to append a newline after
the `?`, but now this reference is gone.

My first answer addressed this, but since it's gone, I'm not sure what you
really want.

---

**NEW ANSWER**

You have to change your `strqclean` function

```
// remove the const from the parameter
void strqclean(char *buffer)
{
  char *p = strchr(buffer,'?');
  if (p != NULL)
    *p = '\n';
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

`strcat` works with pointers, but `strcat` expects C-string and expects that the
destination buffer has enough memory.

`strcat` allows you to connate strings. You can use than to append the `\n` if
the `?` character is always at the end of the string. If the character that
you want to replace is in the middle, the you have to insert the character in
the middle. For that you can use use `memmove` that allows you to move chunks
for memory when the destination and source overlap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[1024] = "Is this the real life?Is this just fantasy";
    char *pos = strchr(line, '?');
    if(pos)
    {
        puts(pos);
        int len = strlen(pos);
        memmove(pos + 2, pos + 1, len);
        pos[1] = '\n';
    }
    puts(line);
    return 0;
}
```